# Creating routes based on dependencies

Tags: servicestack, restangular

I am creating a REST service that will expose for example **customers** and **suppliers** and each have associated **contacts**

I want to be able to route to:

- /contacts
- /contacts/{id}
- /suppliers/{supplierId}/contacts
- /suppliers/{supplierId}/contacts/{id}
- /customers/{customerId}/contacts
- /customers/{customerId}/contacts/{id}

I know I can easily add:

```
[Route("/contacts", "GET")]
[Route("/contacts/{id}", "GET")]
[Route("/{Entity}/{EntityId}/contacts", "GET")]
[Route("/{Entity}/{EntityId}/contacts/{id}", "GET")]
Class ContactsRequest :IReturn<ContactsResponse>{
...
}
```

But I want to be able to use my *Contacts Service* where it could be at the end of a "deeper" route for example:

- /sales/leads/{leadId}/referers/customers/{customerId}/contacts
- /sales/leads/{leadId}/referers/customers/{customerId}/contacts/{id}

I am planing on using this API with restangular, I want to be able to drill down the api from anywhere in the app. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading: http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf

> Now, the relationships can be complex. Owners have relationships with veterinarians, who 
>   have relationships with dogs, who have relationships with food, and so on. It's not 
>   uncommon to see people string these together making a URL 5 or 6 levels deep. Remember 
>   that once you have the primary key for one level, you usually don't need to include the 
>   levels above because you've already got your specific object. In other words, **you shouldn't 
>   need too many cases where a URL is deeper than what we have above** 
>   /resource/identifier/resource.

Basically the design I was after is bad practice...